# Probability of combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I am studying for my discrete math final exam and I am having trouble with this question:

In poker, how many different flush hands (5-card hand with all the same suit) can you have that consist only of hearts, diamonds, or spades?

I tried to solve the question by coming up with a function to solve the amount of ways for one suit then just multiply by 3 to get the total amount for hearts, diamonds, and spades.

Here is what I came up with:

Then multiply the total by 3, so:

2,787,840*3= 8,363,520

However I have a feeling that is very incorrect, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't delete the content of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have a diamond flush, you must have $5$ diamonds. There are $13$ diamonds altogether, and any $5$ of them will give you a flush, so the number of diamond flushes is just the number of $5$-card sets of diamonds. Since in general $\binom{n}k$ is the number of $k$-element subsets of a set of $n$ things, there are $\binom{13}5$ diamond flushes: $n=13$ here, and $k=5$. There are $\binom{13}5$ flushes in each of the four suits, so there are altogether $3\binom{13}5$ flushes in hearts, diamonds, or spades. (In other words, your notion of multiplying the single-suit figure by $3$ is correct; you just didn’t get the single-suit figure right.)

I tried to figure out what you were doing to get the single-suit figure

$$\binom{33}1\binom{12}3\binom42\binom41^3\;,$$

but I’m stumped: I have no idea what you were thinking, so I can’t explain where you went astray.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake for the first one I meant 13c1 as there are that many ways to pick a card. Then I went on and had 12c3 ways to pick up 4. Then for 4c2 I was thinking there are that many ways to pick a pair (I don't really know where I was going with that looking back now). Then for the 4c1 I was thinking there are that many ways to pick a card. I was wayyyy over thinking this. So it would simply be 3(13c5). Thanks for your help :)!

Comment: @pyramid: You’re welcome! (It’s easy to get the idea that counting problems are always tricky, but sometimes they really are simple.)